# Data race with C++ std::future. Compiler reorder

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writing an application that asynchronously accesses a database. In my example serialization is handled by the `handleAllGroups` function. This functions takes a functor, that actually works on the database objects. Since I am not happy with the returned type I wrap up everything in a deferred async call, to create what I want. Everything seems to work smoothly. Still I am a bit concerned about data races since I have no atomic or mutex protection.

QUESTION: May it be possible, that the compiler decides to perform `std::move(*data)` before `fut.wait()`? This is important, since, data is shared with an other thread! (ftor takes shared ownership and is invoked in the database thread, via handleAllGroups)

Any help is appreciated!

```
handleGroupCol_ftor
make_getGroupNamesFtor(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>& data);

std::future<MayBeStrVector>
getAllGroupNames()
{
  // FIXME: This function is fine, but relies on ftor not
  // sharing ownership of data in other places (the move)
  auto data = std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string>>();
  auto ftor = make_getGroupNamesFtor(data);
  return std::async(std::launch::deferred,
        [data](std::future<result>&& fut)->MayBeStrVector{
          fut.wait();
          return {fut.get(), std::move(*data)};
        },
        handleAllGroups(ftor));
}
```

Comment: So you need memory barrier?

Comment: May be, I was actually wondering whether this is the case or not.

Comment: Is the data access in the other thread synchronized with setteing the future?

Comment: Yes, the future is set after the last access to data.

Comment: @T.C. true enough, but handleAllGroups runs async

Comment: What's `MayBeStrVector`?

Comment: Although it's not directly related to your question. Is ther a special reason, why you are using `std::launch::deferred` as a launch policy?

Comment: @MikeMB getAllGroupNames runs async, this is enforced by handleAllGroups. Because of this, there is no need to utilize still another thread just for wrapping the result. The deferred async call will be executed in the thread that calls `getAllGroupNames().get()`, which will then wait for the db thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that all writes to what `data` pointed to on the other thread is sequenced before the making-`fut`-ready, you are safe. [futures.state]/p9:

> Calls to functions that successfully set the stored result of a shared
>   state synchronize with (1.10) calls to functions successfully
>   detecting the ready state resulting from that setting. The storage of
>   the result (whether normal or exceptional) into the shared state
>   synchronizes with (1.10) the successful return from a call to a
>   waiting function on the shared state.

Without getting bogged down in standardese, the *synchronize with* relationship here means that everything that is sequenced before the call that set the stored result in the thread setting the result *happens before* everything sequenced after the `wait()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, future::wait() synchronizes with making the future valid (e.g. return of a async or setting a promise), so what you are doing is safe as far I can tell from that part of the code.

However, I find your using of a shared pointer questionable: Giving a shared pointer to another thread means giving that thread (shared) ownership, but calling std::move on the contents of a shared_ptr is almost as bad as manually calling delete on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, since T.C. quoted the standard I accepted his reply. Concerning your hint: I need an rvalue, would you actually prefer to copy what data points to, and than move that object? To prevent this thread from going off-topic, you could propose a different way by p.m. I would appreciate that .

Comment: @Kuckuck: No wories, T.C.'s answer IS better. As SO doesn't have any PM system I'm aware of I'll answer here: The simplest possibility (minimal number of code changes) would be to use a unique_ptr and pass `data` either via a raw pointer, reference or `const unique_ptr&`. The other possibility would be to restructure your program a little bit. If you put the creation of data and ftor into your lambda, the you wouldn't need to use any pointers at all (create data on the stack and pass references). But of course I cannot say, whether that works with your actual code.

Comment: Oh, isn't there a PM system, I took this for granted. Anyway, thank you for your input, I'll consider it and see if it improves my design.